# Installed python 3.11.5 onto my MAC but my terminal is not recognizing it

Tags: python, macos

In the terminal it still says I am at version 2.7.16. I have run quite a few commands at this point trying to address it, including adding an alias command in my .bash-profile file. I have read a few  posts about changing my PATH file, but I am unsure how to do that on my Mac. Can someone provide some steps I could take to solve this?

Added an alias command in my .bash-profile file. Thought this would default the version of Python to the one I just installed.

I have followed this article as well for reference:

https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

I have linked and unlinked on brew. I have refreshed my -bash.profile file. I have looked at all the other related posts on here regarding this issue and none of the solutions they have provided have helped. Now I feel like I have run a bunch of unrelated commands and may have dug a bigger hole for myself. Please help :(

Comment: What happens if you do `python3 --version`? you generally don't want to override the `python` name since some system packages rely on python version 2